# C# - Inserting Word data to TinyMCE control

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, tinymce

Im using winforms WebBrowser control to show TinyMCE editor to represent an editor with styles that will produce html. I want to insert inside the TinyMCE Editor data I got from word. I tried to convert the data from word to html by saving the document as Html format and then use the setContent function but it lost the font I used in word. I noticed that when I am copying the data from word and pasting it to TinyMCE editor it converts the data somehow without losing the font, so I tried using interop's `Range.Copy` function and paste it to the TinyMCE editor, but I didn't find a way to "call" the paste event on the TinyMCE and send it the data on the clipboard (the problem is calling the event).

How can I trigger the paste event on the editor? im using version 3.1.0.1 of TinyMCE.

is there a known better way to do it?